# Android Studio use shared library in NDK code

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, shared-libraries

Basically, I want to know how to use a c++ shared library in Android Studio *in NDK code (inside jni part)*. There is quite a lot of questions about that but they all are based on changing Android.mk which is not a way to go because in AS it's generated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To use pre built librairies with Android Studio, you have to follow these steps:

1. Compile your C++ librarie with `ndk-build` (here you build librairies for Android architecture such like arm, x86, etc.).
2. Create a Java class and JNI wrapper for your C++ methods.
3. You have then to disable gradle for `ndk-build` and create your own `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` in the jni folder.
4. Import the .so library and pre build it in the `Android.mk`.
5. Invoke `ndk-build` manually, from the Android Studio console.
6. Then, include the header of your librarie and call its functions in your JNI part.

For any complement of information, I advise you the intel video that you can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fEtrekNcOo).

Comment: I mentioned that changing .mk files is _not_ what I am asking for

Comment: Actually, gradle plugin don't support such NDK configuration. If you check that [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio_1.0.0/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/tasks/NdkCompile.groovy)  you can see its limitations. Today, if you want to add pre built libraries to your project you HAVE to use .mk files.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know